# Need to determine the Network Access Type of an Ethernet adapter

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, windows-server-2008-r2

I am in need to trying to figure out the Network Access Type of an ethernet connection on various virtual machines.

In short i am trying to find an analogy for

```
   (Get-NetConnectionProfile).IPv4Connectivity
```

which works great Windows 2012 onwards, i am looking to run this query against Windows 2008 R2 servers.

Comment: All who might face similar issue or have same requirement. I have added the code to the above question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working on a Windows 2008 server, using a .NET class, cast to an object in powershell, Sample code as follows:

```
    $nlm = [Activator]::CreateInstance([Type]::GetTypeFromCLSID([Guid]"{DCB00C01-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B}"))
    $nlm.GetNetworkConnections() | ForEach-Object { 
                                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                                    NetworkName = ($_.GetNetwork().GetName());
                                    isConnectedToInternet = $_.isConnectedToInternet;
                                   } 
    if ($nlm.IsConnectedToInternet)
            {
                $NLAState = 'Internet'
            }
            "Access type : $NLAState"
```